# Fatal doctrine error when populating Elastica Index

Tags: elasticsearch, doctrine, symfony

I'm working on a project in php7, symfony 3.0, elasticsearch 2.3.1 and doctrine.
When i want to execute this command in my terminal in phpstorm, I get this error. Normally everything should work fine.

```
robin@Robin:~/Documents/RoeselareVrijwilligt/VrijwilligersTool$ php bin/console fos:elastica:populate
 11/11 [============================] 100%
Populating homestead/volunteerRefreshing homestead
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRepository() on null in /home/robin/Documents/RoeselareVrijwilligt/VrijwilligersTool/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Doctrine/ORM/Provider.php on line 114


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   
  Error: Call to a member function getRepository() on null  


fos:elastica:populate [--index [INDEX]] [--type [TYPE]] [--no-reset] [--offset OFFSET] [--sleep SLEEP] [--batch-size BATCH-SIZE] [--ignore-errors] [--no-overwrite-format] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Comment: I would considering removing the names from the output snippet.

Comment: His name is also publicly available on his profile, I don't think it matters. :)